# Screenshot (CTRL + SHIFT + PrtScn) not in clipboard

Tags: screenshot

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> has suddenly stopped working.

I'm still able to select an area, but the image is never copied to the clipboard.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Are you sure? I mean, does Shift+PrtScn work? And are you sure you’re pasting the image in a right place? Anyway, check System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots.

Comment: Shift+PrtScn works (and clicking "Copy to Clipbord" works as well).
I'm pasting into Gimp in both cases.
The sound clip also plays.

Comment: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `PrtScn` does copy to the clipboard on my Ubuntu 17.10 running Gnome (some version I don't know how to find out), but `SHIFT`+ `PrtScn` does not copy it to the clipboard

Comment: And obviously there is a bug in StackExchange code that does not allow use of the kbd tag in comments. :(  and apparently that is by design (bad IMO): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132924/142333

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem occurred when I was not starting gnome-settings-daemon. I am using the Awesome window manager and my setup scripts did not start gnome-settings-daemon. For me, just running `gnome-settings-daemon &` in a terminal fixed it. The better solution was to make my Awesome WM startup scripts start it, which makes it automatic.

If you are using the standard Gnome setup (i.e., not using a separate window manager), then this solution probably doesn't apply to you.

Comment: I am just using a stock Ubuntu 14.04. The next time this happens, I will do some more intense logging and might try your fix.

Comment: This solved it for me, I'm now using i3 with a new key assigned to `gnome-screenshot  -c -a -e shadow` for super-fast screenshot region sharing.

Comment: @moodboom Please clarify what i3 means with a link to a website that explains what that is.

Comment: @sqs on Ubuntu 17.10, `which gnome-settings-daemon` returns nothing. `ps -ef --forest --cols=10000 | grep gnome-settings` returns lots of things like `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard` so perhaps this advice is now no longer applicable in recent Ubuntu's?

Comment: @bgoodr  [i3](https://i3wm.org/) is a tiling window manager that can be driven by the keyboard.  I set up keyboard shortcuts to do most things, rather than using a desktop, icons or menus.  You can run that command from a terminal, or set up a shortcut using whatever window manager shortcuts you have available.  But I've now switched to [maim](https://github.com/naelstrof/maim) and slop to capture the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (v16 with cinnamon) and I solved by adding custom shortcuts to the command @moondboom posted in the comment:

[image: screenshot shortcuts]

Go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom shortcuts > Add custom shortcut

- Enter a name
- Enter the command `gnome-screenshot -c -a -e shadow`
- Enter the keyboard bindings